# REGEX Pattern for Validation that check all string is integer and split into single integers

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I tried multiple time to make a pattern that can validate given string is natural number and split into single number.

..and lack of understanding of regex, the closest thing that I can imagine is..

`^([1-9])([0-9])*$` or `^([1-9])([0-9])([0-9])*$` something like that...

It only generates first, last, and second or last-second split-numbers.

I wonder what I need to know to solve this problem.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a two step solution like

```
if (preg_match('~\A\d+\z~', $s)) { // if a string is all digits
    print_r(str_split($s));         // Split it into chars
}
```

See a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/CIEj3p).

A one step regex solution:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\A(?=\d+\z))\d
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7h35MS/2)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\A(?=\d+\z))` - either the end of the previous match (`\G(?!\A)`) or (`|`) the start of string (`^`) that is followed with 1 or more digits up to the end of the string (`(?=\d+\z)`)
- `\d` - a digit.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/GL9krd):

```
$re = '/(?:\G(?!\A)|\A(?=\d+\z))\d/';
$str = '1234567890';
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 0
)
```

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. I'm going to put `(?:\G(?!\A)|\A(?=\d+\z))\d` into regex101 site and examine it.

Comment: If you need more details on, please let me know. The [link](https://regex101.com/r/7h35MS/2) is already in the answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew more specifically to the OP's requirements (no leading zeros) https://regex101.com/r/7h35MS/3

Comment: @mickmackusa Right. Anyway, the solution shows a way to both validate and extract a certain pattern.